# Setting nginx with ssl cant connect from outside

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have setup an new nginx in linux server

with the following sites-enable/

```
server {

        server_name ascohosting.space www.ascohosting.space;

        location / {
        root /var/www/ascohosting.space;
        index index.html index.htm;

        }

    listen *:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ascohosting.space/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ascohosting.space/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {

    if ($host = www.ascohosting.space) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = ascohosting.space) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen *:80 default_server;
        server_name ascohosting.space www.ascohosting.space;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

ufw

```
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and above ufw

but i cant connect from external. what do i miss?
currently using letsencrypt ssl for above.

Router forwarding hasbeen setup too
[image]

Comment: External port number is zero in your router config. Should not it be 80/443 ?

Comment: I cant set it 

it says The configured port conflicts with the internal service port.

i tried many ways wondering still

Comment: i have check the port for 80 external are opened =/ i tried with port 80 nginx works when i changed to SSL it become unconnectable

Comment: If it is reachable from your LAN but not from the public Internet - then the issue is in the router, not in the nginX. If it is not reachable from your internal network - then the problem is not in the router.

Comment: change your protocol on 443 to TLS ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is my route problem. with the setting set by ISP